# react-router-native doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-native

**Error:**
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.context.router.history')

**index.js:**

```
          <Left>

              <Link to="/menu">
                <Image
                  source={require("./src/assets/images/home.png")}
                  style={styles.homeIcon}
                />
              </Link>
          </Left>
...
<NativeRouter>
          <Container>
            <Stack>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
              <Route
                path="/menu"
                component={() => <Menu showMenuIcon={this.showMenuIcon} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="/dialog"
                component={() => <Dialog showMenuIcon={this.showMenuIcon} />}
              />
              ...
            </Stack>
          </Container>
</NativeRouter>
```

After click to **Link** displays an error. What's wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/975

Comment: Surround your entire application with `NativeRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding nativeHistory to your routes

```
import {nativeHistory} from 'react-router-native';

<Router history={nativeHistory}>

</Router>
```

Comment: New error: http://prntscr.com/jnhipw, I doing the right thing? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKoNPZ?editors=0010